# which object pass and how to pass method to cover this portion in test class

Tags: unit-test

```
public static String toConflictFieldName(ObjectType oType) {
        if (oType == ObjectType.ACCOUNT) {
            return 'SalesForceAccount__c';
        } else if (oType == ObjectType.CONTACT) {
            return 'Contact__c';
        } else {
            return 'Lead__c';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Need more detail to understand what it try to do.But perhap something like this test class just call it by

```
Account a = new Account();
Contact c =new Contact();
AnyObject__c obj = new AnyObject__c();
String str1 =toConflictFieldName(a);
String str2 =toConflictFieldName(c);
String str3 =toConflictFieldName(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

When writing logic that handles different SObjects and different SObject fields, [SObjectType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm) and [SObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm) are the appropriate classes to use. They make it clear what you are dealing with (compared to using String) and also provide methods that can be useful. They also allow the Apex compiler to check your code for consistency with your data model.

Using this approach, your method would look like this:

```
public static SObjectField toConflictField(SObjectType sobType) {
    if (sobType == Account.SObjectType) {
        return Account.SalesForceAccount__c;
    } else if (sobType == Contact.SObjectType) {
        return Contact.Contact__c;
    } else {
        // Not sure what SObject to use here
        return Lead.Lead__c;
    }
}
```

and you might use it like this:

```
SObject sob = ...;

SObjectField field = toConflictField(sob.getSObjectType());
Id value = (Id) sob.get(field);
```

(making use of the [base SObject class methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)).

To test the method:

```
System.assertEquals(
        Account.SalesForceAccount__c,
        YourClassName.toConflictField(Account.SObjectType)
        );
System.assertEquals(
        Contact.Contact__c,
        YourClassName.toConflictField(Contact.SObjectType)
        );
System.assertEquals(
        Lead.Lead__c,
        YourClassName.toConflictField(Lead.SObjectType)
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dis..

```
  public static string toConflictFieldName(Object o) {
if(o instanceof ACCOUNT)               return 'SalesForceAccount__c';
if(o instanceof Lead)                  return 'Lead__c';
if(o instanceof Contact)               return 'contact__c';

return 'Object';}
```

function call

```
Lead l=new Lead();ClassName.toConflictFieldName(l);
```

Comment: i tried this Method does not exist or incorrect signature: ConflictManager.toConflictFieldName(Lead